# Multiple DBs in server handler

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm following the directory structure followed in the repository https://github.com/victorsteven/Go-JWT-Postgres-Mysql-Restful-API/blob/master/api/controllers/base.gohttps://github.com/victorsteven/Go-JWT-Postgres-Mysql-Restful-API/blob/master/api/controllers/base.go. I am trying to develop a dual DB client to for my project, where I need to connect to Mongo and MYSQL database severs. And I made some changes to the code and I just wanted to check whether it's a best practice to do this.  Can we place dual DB client in the handler?

package controllers

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"    //mysql database driver
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres" //postgres database driver
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"   // sqlite database driver
    "github.com/victorsteven/fullstack/api/models"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

type Server struct {
    DB     *gorm.DB
    Router *mux.Router
    MongoClient *mongo.Client 
}

func (server *Server) Initialize(Dbdriver, DbUser, DbPassword, DbPort, DbHost, DbName string) {

    var err error
    mongoURL := "mongodb://localhost:27017"
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURL))
       ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)

    // Ping MongoDB
    ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    if err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("could not ping to mongo db service: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("connected to nosql database:", mongoURL)
    server.MongoClient = client


    if Dbdriver == "mysql" {
        DBURL := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local", DbUser, DbPassword, DbHost, DbPort, DbName)
        server.DB, err = gorm.Open(Dbdriver, DBURL)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Cannot connect to %s database", Dbdriver)
            log.Fatal("This is the error:", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("We are connected to the %s database", Dbdriver)
        }
    }
    if Dbdriver == "postgres" {
        DBURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s", DbHost, DbPort, DbUser, DbName, DbPassword)
        server.DB, err = gorm.Open(Dbdriver, DBURL)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Cannot connect to %s database", Dbdriver)
            log.Fatal("This is the error:", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("We are connected to the %s database", Dbdriver)
        }
    }
    if Dbdriver == "sqlite3" {
        //DBURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s", DbHost, DbPort, DbUser, DbName, DbPassword)
        server.DB, err = gorm.Open(Dbdriver, DbName)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Cannot connect to %s database\n", Dbdriver)
            log.Fatal("This is the error:", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("We are connected to the %s database\n", Dbdriver)
        }
        server.DB.Exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
    }

    server.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(&models.User{}, &models.Post{}) //database migration

    server.Router = mux.NewRouter()

    server.initializeRoutes()
}

func (server *Server) Run(addr string) {
    fmt.Println("Listening to port 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(addr, server.Router))
}
```

Comment: "Can we place dual DB client in the handler?" -- Of course you can. You can do whatever you want. What problem are you facing?

Comment: As a side note: Imho, that is a Very Bad Idea™: you clutter your code more than necessary. Have two microservices communicate with each other. There is a plethora of options available, from a simple use of `encoding/json` over [`msgpack`](https://msgpack.org/) to something as advanced as [grpc](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/)

Comment: Since I'm new to go. I was following some references, defining the global variables for database is not a good idea and we will face issue in the test case development. I wanted to know if there is any side effects like connection pooling and all.

Comment: AFAIK, Mongo doesn't use connection pooling, since it's HTTP-based.  But even if it did, I'm not sure why you think that would be a problem, or how it relates to this question.

Comment: BTW, note that you should never do this: `ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(...`  You must _always_ call the `cancel` function, or you'll have memory leaks.